# How can I create a user account without password?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to create a second user account with limited permissions which I can use as a honeypot if someone steals my MacBook, but it refuses to allow a standard user without a password. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I'd just pick an easy to guess password. If I were going to steal a laptop, I'd assume an unprotected account had nothing valuable in it and spend my time trying to get into the protected account.

Comment: Why would you want an account with no password?

Comment: @OzzieSpin I explained this in my question.

Comment: There’s definitely a way to do this. I have seen it.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/change-account-password-to-blank

Comment: have you tried setting the password to nothing?  just hit return to login.

Answer (score 1):

Write the password clearly within the password hint field. You might have to surround it with some extra non-password text. 
For example, the hint —

> Forgot your 9-character password? It's not qwerty1234 of course

would be crackable (probably first time) by any kid who thinks about it for five seconds. Mac OS will allow multiple attempts.